# Check if template argument is a member function of another

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have a function that maps `std::optional`-s to their value invoked with a function if they have any, otherwise returns an empty optional. The case where the function itself expects an `optional` as an argument should not be allowed. In my implementation, I would like to provide diagnostics, whether this operation is feasible.

However, the problem I face is that when I would like to check for functions accepting optionals, `std::is_invocable` returns true for member functions. For example, this is perfectly valid (as `std::invoke` [tries to match](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) the function against `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` as well):

```cpp
std::optional<std::string> o{"313"};
std::cout << std::invoke(&std::string::size, o) << std::endl;
```

I have this kind of signature for my function (simplified for F to be taken by value):

```cpp
template <typename Opt, typename F>
auto fun(Opt&& opt, F f) {
   // (...)
   constexpr bool IsMemberFunctionOfOptionalValue = ???;
   static_assert(IsMemberFunctionOfOptionalValue || !std::is_invocable_v<F, std::decay_v<Opt>>, "Ambiguous call for function accepting optional, (...)";
   // (...)
}
```

Unfortunately, any check involving writing something like `typename std::decay_t<Opt>::value_type::F` is a compilation error as it tries to search for a function called 'F':

```cpp
std::is_member_function_pointer<typename Opt::value_type::F> // error: no type named 'F' in 'std::basic_string<char>'.
```

I am looking for way of checking whether a function is directly callable on an optional, but not because it results to a member function access. **I think the missing link for this is checking whether a template argument is a member function on another, but alternate solutions are welcome**. The codebase I am on is using c++17.

Comment: Are there any cases where you do want a member function pointer to be a valid `F` argument?

Comment: So `std::is_invocable_v<F, std::decay_t<Opt>> && !(std::is_member_function_pointer_v<F> && is_optional_v<Opt>)` where you need `is_optional_v`?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, say I have the optional o from the first example, I want fun(&std::string::size, o.value()); to be a valid expression.

Comment: is_optional_v is checked for beforehand. However, F needs not only to be a member function pointer, but a member function pointer of Opt::value_type

Comment: What about a member of a base class of `Opt::value_type`? If it's neither of those, `is_invocable` will be false anyway.

Comment: @aschepler I think you mean checking if the function is invocable with the value type? Unfortunately, you can invoke a function of a signature f(std::optional<std::string>) with the value type itself (eg. "std::invoke(f, o.value());" is valid).

Comment: In the case where you know `Opt` is `std::optional<V>`, when does `(std::is_invocable_v<F, std::decay_t<Opt>> && !std::is_member_function_pointer_v<F>)` give the wrong result? If `F` points at a member of some unrelated class, `is_invocable_v` will be false, so why bother trying to separately check the class owning `F`?

Comment: (And I think you might want to check any pointer-to-member, not just pointer-to-member-function. `fun(&std::pair<int, int>::first, std::optional<std::pair<int, int>>{})` would have the same problem.)

Comment: @aschepler I see what you mean, F can be only a member function on the value type, if I directly call invoke on the value: https://godbolt.org/z/6PMnPTcaY If you extract this to an answer this is an actual solution to my problem I think.